# Dimension of the dual of a finite-dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My book defines the dual space $V^\ast$ of a vector space $V$ as the set of the linear application in $V$. Then it says ...

> **Theorem:** If $V$ is a vector space of limited dimension on the $K$ field, so the dual space $V^\ast$ have limited dimension and ...
>
> ... $\dim V^\ast = \dim V$.

Now, if the dimension of a space is the number of vectors needed to generate the entire space, how is it possible to generate an infinite number of possible linear applications by a limited basis?

Is it possible because the linear applications can be summed and multiplicated by constants? Im just not sure...

Comment: Yes, it's because you're allowed to use infinitely many constants. I'm not sure what dual spaces have to do with your question, though.

Comment: Are you concerned about the dimension of the dual space, OP? I'm struggling to interpret what your question is about. Why is the dual space mentioned here?

Comment: Yes, it is because the number of constants are infinite. Look at the real line. It is a vector space.Say you take any vector, say 1, and you can multiply it by what scalar you like, say 1,2,3,4,$\pi$,$\sqrt(2)$, or whatever scalar you like, and there are uncountable infinite number of these scalars.

Comment: You could ask the same question for $K^n$, which is infinite (if $K$ is infinite, such as in the case of $K=\mathbb{R}$) and yet it has a finite basis.

Comment: Got it. Thanks :)

Comment: It would be nice if someone turned his/her comment to an answer to this question. I mean having non-answered by actually answer questions is not nice.